# How to get the high and low of previous candle

Tags: pine-script

I feel like this is a fairly simple question but I can't find the answer. I just need to set a stop loss at the high of the previous candle

Answer (score 1):

Getting any value from the previous candle would just need `[1]` put after it. For example, the high of the previous candle would be `high[1]` and the previous close would be `close[1]`

Comment: With index `[1]` you will always get the last candle high, so with every candle in the future, that previous high will move forward, it will not be a static SL, for that you can use `valuewhen(your_condition, high[1], 0)`, this way will cast the previous high from your entry condition and will stay at that level